# C# Reflection: Get calling class' Type

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reflection in C#: How do I get the calling method name and type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/reflection-in-c-how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type)

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        Bar.Pirate();
    }
}

public static class Bar {
    public static void Pirate() {
        Type callingClassType = ...
    }
}
```

Within `Pirate()`, how do I get the `Type` of the class (`Foo`) that called `Pirate()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/reflection-in-c-how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type  Although, I think looking into the stack trace is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get it efficiently. As a point of design, I think it's better to pass the calling class type into the Pirate method.

If you can't pass the class type as a parameter then you can get the calling type from the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class in the System.Diagnostics namespace, but if my memory is correct it's a fairly expensive class to use.