# Get full caller MethodInfo and/or Type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm wondering is there is a better or newer way to get the caller MethodInfo.

The only solution I have seen is using the [StackFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection), though people mention that it's not always reliable in release builds. And it does not seem to work with async calls either :(

Alternative, I can use the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), but that will only give me the method name as a string.
It will be impossible to find any custom attributes on that method without knowing the class type (which is my intention).

Could I do something with the [CallerFilePathAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Note that inlining means that the stack-frame approach isn't actually reliable, unless you explicitly disable inlining for both caller and callee - which is usually a bad thing to do. What is it that you actually want to do here? there may be better approaches. And `[CallerFilePath]` has very limited uses (it does have some though; we use it to inject the caller into our SQL as a comment, so it is easy to see what is causing SQL ops that show up on our performance dashboard.

Comment: I had some ideas that would require me to analyze the attributes defined on the caller method and perform specific actions on it. In theory, it would look very nice, but I guess that it's indeed not very practical :)

Comment: another possibility is something like postsharp

Comment: Yes, but we don't use it :) That would have solved a lot