# How does a Property type passed to a function set the parameter value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, custom-attributes

I'm looking at a solution for getting the class name of a calling method in .Net 4.5 and I'm hoping to use a custom property attribute to implement it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection) is an example of using the System attribute CallerMemberName to get the member name but for my own attribute I'm not sure which functions to implement to return a value.

Does anyone know of links to more documentation on implementing this type of attribute or of any examples?

So far I'm planning on using the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    //some method to implement returning the attribute value
}

class CallerTestClass
{
    public string GetCallerClass(
        [MyAttribute]string className = "")
    {
        return className;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the formatting help for how to post blocks of code - use indentation instead of `<code>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, basically. The C# compiler has special knowledge of the `CallerMemberName` attribute - it *doesn't* have special knowledge of your attribute.

It sounds like you should just be able to use `CallerMemberName` though, rather than having your own attribute at all...

Comment: Well I need the calling class, not calling method. There is a way to get the assembly information using CallerFilePath but I was hoping I could do it more efficient than parsing the assembly for the class information each time the method is called

Comment: @ars265: No, there isn't. And of course the file may not match the class name.