# Get the Type of a Variable Being Assigned to From Within a Method

Tags: c#

I want to create a method that takes a dynamic input parameter and returns a dynamic that I can use to fill a typed variable.  Is there a way to get the type of the variable being assigned to from within the method?

```
double dbl = AssignValue("Hello");

public dynamic AssignValue(dynamic ValueToAssign)
{
    Type type = //do something to get the type of variable "dbl"

    switch (type.Name)
    {
        case "Double":
             return double.Parse(AssignValue);
             break;
        case "Decimal":
             return decimal.Parse(AssignValue);
             break;
        //...
    }    
}
```

I tried to locate something in the StackFrame but, with no luck.

Any terminology to research further would be very much appreciated as well.

Comment: typeOf(ValueToAssign) or ValueToAssign.GetType()

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: He wants `double`, not `string`.  Also, `typeof(variable)` is illegal.

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned how to get the type of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the type of the variable being assigned to from within the method?

No.  There is no way for a method to retrieve any information about the variable that its result will be assigned to.

However, you could use generics to *tell* the method the type of object you want it to return:

```
double dbl = AssignValue<double>("Hello");

public T AssignValue<T>(object valueToAssign)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    switch(type.Name)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am looking into these now.  I guess I was assuming it *might* be possible because you are able to do similar things like, use StackFrame to get the name of the calling method, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection

Comment: Ok, telling me that it's not possible is as good an answer as any so, I'll use this option you provided instead.  Thanks very much!