# Getting the name of the declaring class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection

Suppose I got a parent class and a child class:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public string GetParentName()
    {
        return GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string GetChildName()
    {
        return GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

As of current, both **GetParentName()** and **GetChildName()** will return *Child*.

However, in my scenario, I'd like to get the name of the class in which the method is declared.

Thus **GetChildName()** should return *Child* but **GetParentName()** should return *Parent*.

Is this by any means possible?

**NOTE:**

> I understand that I could use GetType().BaseType.Name but this
>   won't work since the hierarchy could be complex.

Comment: `I'd like to get the name of the class in which the method is declared` i mean they are two different methods, `GetChildName` *is* declared in the child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the calling method name and type using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection)

Comment: You could simply return "Parent". Give us an exemple where returning a string litteral isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want this, I think:

```
return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Comment: You could also use this, if you want to be able to get the declaring type from somewhere outside of the function in question:    
    typeof(Child).GetMembers().First(m => m.Name == "GetParentName").DeclaringType.Name