# using CallerMemberName and MethodImplOptions.NoInlining - Is it necessary?

Tags: c#, attributes, .net-4.5

Quick background:
Trying to create a method that will return a pre-defined string based on the method that calls it. (bit glossed over but near enough).

I am intending to use the [[`CallerMemberName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)] Attribute, but my question is:

=> Do I need to use the `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` with this attribute, or is that implicitly applied by the compiler?

There are many examples of both the `CallerMemberName` attribute, and the older version for pre .net4.5 frameworks which use `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` method attribute but nothing which explicitly say that you dont need to use them together?

Thanks in advance, and for reading!

Comment: "Do I need to use the MethodImplOptions.NoInlining with this attribute, or is that implicitly applied by the compiler?" Why? What problem are you trying to solve? What did you try to diagnose/solve that?

Comment: What i identified was that the `NoInlining` Attribute would cause the compiler to deoptimise that section of code, so that you wouldnt get the caller of the caller name. What i thought was that the `CallerMemberName` attribute would have the same issue unless it had this inlining turned off implicitly? Just trying to clarify the situation on it. More preventative, rather than fixing a bug.

Comment: Can you show a code sample that you think benefits of that attribute?

Comment: It was a question on SO that made me consider it, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection the comments mention using the attribute to prevent inlining.  Seems like EvK has the answer though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary because [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx) is resolved by compiler at compile time:

> Caller Info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate
>   Language (IL) at compile time.

Inlining is done not by C# compiler but by JIT when compiling your IL code to assembly, so inlining cannot affect functionality provided by `CallerMemberName`.