# How to use CallerMemberName with an interface method

Tags: c#, .net

I am navigating through some 700K lines of code.   A lot of interface implementation and DI usage.   I am trying to figure out where a particular method is getting called from, hence I am trying to use `[CallerMemberName]`.

All the examples I see on google etc are something like this:

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
```

Where optional parms are used to get the info.   My problem is that this method is part of an interface implementation. So, when I change the method signature the compiler is yelling at me.

Any suggestions on how to make an interface method play nice with `[CallerMembername]` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will probably need to change the interface and any implementations along with it, but it's hard to tell what you mean. It would help to clarify what change you actually tried to make.

Comment: @Mike Zboray Thanks for asking.   I tried adding the optional parms like the example above.   I was hoping since those parms are optional the compiler won't care.  Changing the interface is tricky because this means changing a crap ton of code.

Comment: So you've got some interface method like ILogger.TraceMessage(string) and you want to know who is calling it? And let's say its implemented in Logger, you changed Logger.TraceMessage to add the optionals?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Neither adding a default value to a parameter, nor adding the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute to a parameter, on a method that implements a member of some interface does not cause a compile-time error. Writing something like _"...the compiler is yelling at me"_ is not a useful problem description. It is neither precise nor accurate. If you are having trouble, post a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, explain _exactly_ what happens with that code, including the _exact_ text of any error message, and what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar issue - found that I could add CallerMemberName to an interface method as follows. It does change the signature for the implementing class but not for calling code - if that makes sense!

If this is the method's current signature in the interface

```
void TraceMessage(string message);
```

Change as follows

```
void TraceMessage(string message,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0);
```

Update the method in the class that implements the interface

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        //  Log the params
    }
```

This can still be called with the original signature using just the 'message' param, and the other params will still be picked up, so no need to refactor all calling code

```
TraceMessage("Testing");
```

(Add for brevity)

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

Comment: superb (thumbs up)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a caller name in a different way without changing any signatures, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171974/11843739)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
// Get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// Get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

This solution is much slower than compile-time that you are trying to use, but it is much less intrusive.

If performance is critical and you are using DI with IoC containers, then you may check if it supports aspects, like [Unity.Interception](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Interception/) or [Ninject.Extensions.Interception](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Interception/). You'll need to implement an aspect (interceptor) and register it in the container, [here](https://koukia.ca/implementing-a-caching-layer-with-unity-interceptor-leveraging-cachemanager-open-source-library-25633075858a) is an example with caching interceptor.

If you don't use IoC, you can still use AOP approach and add a certain aspect to the methods that you are interested in. [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) can do that, but it is not a free tool, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115909/any-free-alternative-to-postsharp) are some alternatives.

Comment: This option has issues as the caller or the called may be inlined.

Comment: @Maslow I don't think there is any issue related to the method inlining optimization as it'd done by JIT - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47138358/11843739

Comment: This specific solution uses `StackTrace`, not CallerMember attributes, so inlining would effect it.

Comment: My bad, I messed up with the answers, you are right.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028515/57883