# Why CallerClassName (or CallerTypeName or similar) attribute does not exist?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

There are some attributes like `CallerMemberName` in C# that are quite handy especially for the logging purposes. What everyone (or at least me anyway) seems to be lacking is `CallerClassName` so that we can easily log something like this without explicitly passing `this` or a string with the class name:

> Exception happened during MyClass.MyMethod execution

Are there any restrictions that makes it easy to know the method but not class or is it just a missing feature that we probably can ask to add?

Comment: "Why" is a question that only the .NET team can answer, so that's not actually on-topic here. You may want to look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method/37885619#37885619) though

Comment: Well, I suppose it's quite legit, since it's logical and there are probably some technical reasons I have not thought about that can be the reason. It's not like it's opinion-based :). Thanks for the reference

Comment: Before `nameof()` you could use this to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` without having to hardcode property names. I can imagine they had that goal in mind, and had no need to add others. Just guessing, though.

Comment: Would be superfluent if you ask me since you have the stacktrace along with the exception ...

Comment: Why don't you use the `nameof` operator? `string s = $"Exception happened during {nameof(MyClass)}.{nameof(MyClass.MyMethod)} execution";`

Comment: @Fildor It's not always the exception that is logged

Comment: @mm8 Because I don't want to pass this each time to the logger, so that I can have some context information in there automagically. It's of course easy to do it this way.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Ah, I inferred that from your example. What logging framework are you using? There may be other ways ...

Comment: How about using the `StackFrame` class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095696/how-do-i-get-the-calling-method-name-and-type-using-reflection

Comment: @Fildor I use serilog, but I don't really think there is any way without directly passing something or maybe analyzing stack which both seems too cumbersome, so that's why I was wondering why does this attribute not exist :)