# Is there any way to get the PropertyInfo from the getter of that property?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, propertyinfo

Is there any way I can get the `PropertyInfo` for a property from its getter? Like this:

```
public object Foo
{
    get
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfoForFoo = xxx;
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to avoid having to hard code the name of the property as a string, as that's tricky to maintain.

I'm using .NET 2.0, so I'm hoping for a linq-less solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current property name via reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206023/how-to-get-current-property-name-via-reflection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() will return the MethodInfo object for get_YourPropertyName.

```
PropertyInfo property = GetType()
                            .GetProperty(MethodBase
                                             .GetCurrentMethod()
                                             .Name
                                             .Substring("get_".Length)
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Um... So how were you planning on being "given" the getter?

The only way I see is by something like `MyGetProperyInfo(x => x.Foo);`

which can be done, although it requires a lambda & an Expression<> (neither of which is available in C# v2)

Comment: Lambdas are available in c# 2, just not linq. Not sure about Expression<>.

Comment: @JOnB: `Expression` and all subtypes are implemented in the System.Core assembly, and were added in .NET 3.5.