# How to get a unique identifier of a property from within its accessors

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is it possible to get a unique identifier of a property from within its accessors?

```
class Foo
{
    int Bar
    {
        set
        {
            string nameOfThisProperty = X; // where X == "Bar" or any unique value
        }
    }
}
```

If so, how?

**Update**:

The reason I'm asking is: I want some some consistent unique value identifying the property in which the code is executing to avoid having to declare one myself as I'm doing right now:

```
Dictionary<string, RelayCommand> _relayCommands 
    = new Dictionary<string, RelayCommand>();

public ICommand SomeCmd
{
    get
    {
        string commandName = "SomeCmd";
        RelayCommand command;
        if (_relayCommands.TryGetValue(commandName, out command))
            return command;
        ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current property name via reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206023/how-to-get-current-property-name-via-reflection)

Comment: There are a lot of methods to achieve this. The best one depends on the reason you need it. To implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Adriano: I updated with my reason for asking.

Comment: See the post of @empi but remember to add MethodImplOptions.NoInlining. If you're using .NET 4.5 (or you know you'll use it) take a look to CallerMemberNameAttribute (and it's even resolved at compile time!).

Comment: check this link [Get string name of property using reflection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
set
{
    string name = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
    // TODO: strip the set_ prefix from the name
}
```

As pointed out in the comments section the setter could be inlined so it must be decorated with the `[MethodImpl]` attribute to prevent the JITer from doing so.

Also you will have to strip the `set_` prefix from the method name because name will equal `set_Bar`.

So:

```
string name = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4);
```

Comment: The method will be (or could be) inlined. He should mark it as non inlined.

Comment: @sixfeetsix if the property setter is simple enough (as it should almost always be) it'll be inlined by the JIT compiler. In this case the name of the current method is not set_propertyName but the name of the caller. It should mark a method as  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]

Comment: @Adriano, excellent remark. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: +1 This is the fastest method to get the property name in .NET 3.x and 4.0!

Comment: @Adriano: is it the fastest when you factor in the hit from disallowing inlining?

Comment: @sixfeetsix fastest compared with StackFrame and Expressions! The Noinline is the price we have to pay... :(