# Is there a way in C# to turn the property into a string containing it's name?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I'd like to get a string representation given a property. This way I can use this string for `NotifyPropertyChanged` and stil be ok after a refactoring of the property's name.

EDIT: I'm using .NET 4.0

UPDATE: I'd also like to have the name available for `DependencyProprty`s, i.e. I need the value during static variable assignment time.

Same sample code to explain:

```
// actual code

private int prop = 42;
public int Prop
{
    get
    {
        return prop;
    }
    set
    {
        prop = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop"); // I'd like to replace the hard-coded string here
    }
}


// code as I'd like it to be

private int propNew = 42;
private static readonly string PropNewName = GainStringFromPropertySomeHow(PropNew); // should be "PropNew"
public int PropNew
{
    get
    {
        return propNew;
    }
    set
    {
        propNew = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(PropNewName); // <== will remain correct even if PropNew name is changed
    }
}
```

After refactoring:

```
private int prop = 42;
public int PropNameChanged
{
    get
    {
        return prop;
    }
    set
    {
        prop = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop"); // oops
    }
}


private int propNew = 42;
private static readonly string PropNewName = GainStringFromPropertySomeHow(PropNewNameChanged); // should be "PropNewNameChanged"
public int PropNewNameChanged
{
    get
    {
        return propNew;
    }
    set
    {
        propNew = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(PropNewName); // still correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be helpfull:

```
// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
```

Source and more explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

And here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx

Comment: Would be a nice solution, but I'm using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not yet on .Net 4.5 and thus cannot use CallerMemberName, you can use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191598/869250

Comment: Looks similar to the solution I found in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [How to get current property name via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206023/how-to-get-current-property-name-via-reflection)

So you can just do this

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here on Stackoverflow:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/672212/1254743](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820759/1254743)

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820759/1254743

The resulting code:

```
public static class PropertyNameExtractor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Usage: PropertyNameExtractor.ExposeProperty(() => this.YourProperty)
    /// yields: "YourProperty"
    /// </summary>
    public static string ExposeProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var expression = GetMemberInfo(property);
        return expression.Member.Name;

    }

    private static MemberExpression GetMemberInfo(Expression method)
    {
        LambdaExpression lambda = method as LambdaExpression;
        if (lambda == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("method");

        MemberExpression memberExpr = null;

        if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            memberExpr =
                ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpr == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        return memberExpr;
    }

}
```

In my class:

```
class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.nameOf_MyProperty = PropertyNameExtractor.ExposeProperty(() => this.MyProperty);

    }


    private readonly string nameOf_MyProperty;
    private int myProperty = 42 ;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            myProperty= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameOf_MyProperty);
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```